# TrueSkill Implementation in R

Tags: r, algorithm

I am trying to program the basic [Vanilla TrueSkill (3.1)](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/74417/NIPS2007_0931.pdf) algorithm in R but am getting some strange results.

My code is the following:

```
# A simple test between two players repeatedly laying one another
betaSq = 0.1
obs = 10000

p1_skills = 0.333
p2_skills = 0

p1_draws = rnorm(obs, p1_skills, sqrt(betaSq))
p2_draws = rnorm(obs, p2_skills, sqrt(betaSq))

p1_pred_mu = rep(NA, obs+1)
p1_pred_sigmaSq = rep(NA, obs+1)
p2_pred_mu = rep(NA, obs+1)
p2_pred_sigmaSq = rep(NA, obs+1)

# Initial values
p1_pred_mu[1] = 0
p1_pred_sigmaSq[1] = 1
p2_pred_mu[1] = 0
p2_pred_sigmaSq[1] = 1

results = p1_draws > p2_draws
probs = rep(NA, obs)

# Run TrueSkill
for (i in seq(2,obs+1)) {
  probs[i-1] = predictProb(p1_pred_mu[i-1], p1_pred_sigmaSq[i-1], p2_pred_mu[i-1], p2_pred_sigmaSq[i-1], betaSq)
  out = updateSkill(p1_pred_mu[i-1], p1_pred_sigmaSq[i-1], p2_pred_mu[i-1], p2_pred_sigmaSq[i-1], betaSq, results[i-1])

  # Now update based on the out  
  p1_pred_mu[i] = out$mu1
  p1_pred_sigmaSq[i] = out$sigmaSq1
  p2_pred_mu[i] = out$mu2
  p2_pred_sigmaSq[i] = out$sigmaSq2
}

# Output results
dev.new()
mu = p1_pred_mu
lower = qnorm(0.05, p1_pred_mu, p1_pred_sigmaSq)
upper = qnorm(0.95, p1_pred_mu, p1_pred_sigmaSq)
plot(mu, ylim = c(min(lower), max(upper)), main = "p1")
lines(lower)
lines(upper)

dev.new()
mu = p2_pred_mu
lower = qnorm(0.05, p2_pred_mu, p2_pred_sigmaSq)
upper = qnorm(0.95, p2_pred_mu, p2_pred_sigmaSq)
plot(mu, ylim = c(min(lower), max(upper)), main = "p2")
lines(lower)
lines(upper)

a = filter(probs, rep(1, 20))/20
dev.new()
plot(a)

print(sprintf("Mean p1: %g", mean(p1_pred_mu)))
print(sprintf("Mean p2: %g", mean(p2_pred_mu)))
print(sprintf("Mean results: %g", mean(results)))
print(sprintf("Mean predicted results: %g", mean(probs)))
```

The functions that are called are:

```
# Functions
updateSkill <- function(mu1, sigmaSq1, mu2, sigmaSq2, betaSq, result) {
  # http://papers.nips.cc/paper/3331-trueskill-through-time-revisiting-the-history-of-chess.pdf
  c = 2*betaSq + sigmaSq1 + sigmaSq2

  if (result == 1) {
    # Player 1 wins
    v = dnorm((mu1-mu2)/c)/pnorm((mu1-mu2)/c)
    w = v*(v+(mu1-mu2)/c)

    mu1 = mu1 + (sigmaSq1/c)*v
    mu2 = mu2 - (sigmaSq2/c)*v

    sigmaSq1 = sigmaSq1 * sqrt(1 - (sigmaSq1/c^2)*w)
    sigmaSq2 = sigmaSq2 * sqrt(1 - (sigmaSq2/c^2)*w)
  } else if (result == 0) {
    # Player 2 wins
    v = dnorm((mu2-mu1)/c)/pnorm((mu2-mu1)/c)
    w = v*(v+(mu2-mu1)/c)

    mu1 = mu1 - (sigmaSq1/c)*v
    mu2 = mu2 + (sigmaSq2/c)*v

    sigmaSq1 = sigmaSq1 * sqrt(1 - (sigmaSq1/c^2)*w)
    sigmaSq2 = sigmaSq2 * sqrt(1 - (sigmaSq2/c^2)*w)    
  }

  return(list(mu1=mu1, mu2=mu2, sigmaSq1=sigmaSq1, sigmaSq2=sigmaSq2))
}

predictProb <- function(mu1, sigmaSq1, mu2, sigmaSq2, betaSq) {
  # Try to predict the probability of player 1 beating player 2 using Trueskill model
  mean1 = mu1
  mean2 = mu2
  var1 = sigmaSq1 + betaSq
  var2 = sigmaSq2 + betaSq

  # Now the dist of player1 - player2 is N(mean1 - mean2, sqrt(var1 + var2))
  prob1Wins = pnorm(0, mean2 - mean1, sqrt(var1 + var2))

  return(prob1Wins)
}
```

I hate to post the massive code blob but I really cannot figure out where things are going wrong.

This program runs and the predicted skills (distributed to a N(mu, sigma)) converge. However the predicted probabilities they are giving are not converging to the true probabilities for the results!

A sample output is:

```
[1] "Mean p1: 0.0762161"
[1] "Mean p2: -0.0762161"
[1] "Mean results: 0.7733"
[1] "Mean predicted results: 0.631424"
```

Any idea what is going wrong?

Comment: I doubt this is it but if you're sharing code note that you can't use functions before they're defined.  Reorganize your code so that the functions you use are defined before they're called

Comment: Yep, they are actually in another file and I source them. I'll make that clearer.

Answer (score 1):

The reason this didn't work is because in the 3rd line of the updateSkills function it should read

```
c = sqrt(2*betaSq + sigmaSq1 + sigmaSq2)
```

not

```
c = 2*betaSq + sigmaSq1 + sigmaSq2
```